# Linux - read or collect file content faster (e.g. cpu temp every sec.)

Tags: linux, shell

I'm working on a system on which ubuntu is running. I'm reading basic data like CPU frequency and temperature out of the thermal zones provided in /sys/class/thermal.

Unfortunately, I've got around 100 thermal_zones from which I need to read the data. I do it with:

```
for SENSOR_NODE in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*; do printf "%s: %s\n" $(cat ${SENSOR_NODE}/type) $(cat ${SENSOR_NODE}/temp); done
```

To collect all data takes ~2.5-3 sec. which is way to long.
Since I want to collect the data every second my question is, if there is a way to "read" or "collect" the data faster?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use `cat` or any other external command. Stick to the bash built-in `$(<name)` or (slower but more portable) `read`, and avoid command substitutions altogether.

Comment: If that's not good enough, you'll want to move away from shell. For example, awk has much better IO performance than typical shells do, but you need to do the whole loop inside awk, not tell a shell to run awk over and over. Really, though, if I were in your shoes I'd write this in Go.

Comment: (I specifically recommend Go because goroutines and channels allow optimizations for this kind of program that are a lot of trouble to implement in C; but Python or node.js or really any other mainstream general purpose language will still be better than what you have now)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Never heard of Go before. Sounds like an interesting approach :D.

Comment: It's the language a lot of widely used monitoring tools are written in today, so you shouldn't have any trouble finding real works examples. I'd be shocked if you couldn't find a program written on Go monitoring these exact same probes already.

Comment: (...yup -- it's included in the [prometheus node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/collector/thermal_zone_linux.go), which uses the library https://github.com/prometheus/procfs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only so much you can do while writing your code in shell, but let's start with the basics.

- Command substitutions, `$(...)`, are expensive: They require creating a FIFO, `fork()`ing a new subprocess, connecting the FIFO to that subprocess's stdout, reading from the FIFO and waiting for the commands running in that subshell to exit.
- External commands, like `cat`, are expensive: They require linking and loading a separate executable; and when you run them without `exec` (in which case they inherit and consume the shell's process ID), they *also* require a new process to be `fork()`ed off.

All POSIX-compliant shells give you a `read` command:

```
for sensor_node in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*; do
  read -r sensor_type <"$sensor_node/type" || continue
  read -r sensor_temp <"$sensor_node/temp" || continue
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$sensor_type" "$sensor_temp"
done
```

...which lets you avoid the command substitution overhead and the overhead of `cat`. However, `read` reads content only one byte at a time; so while you're not paying that overhead, it's still relatively slow.

If you switch from `/bin/sh` to `bash`, you get a faster alternative:

```
for sensor_node in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*; do
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$(<"$sensor_node/type)" "$(<"$sensor_node/temp")"
done
```

...as `$(<file)` doesn't need to do the one-byte-at-a-time reads that `read` does. That's only faster *for being bash*, though; it doesn't mean it's actually *fast*. There's a reason modern production monitoring systems are typically written in [Go](https://go.dev/) or with a JavaScript runtime like Node.

Comment: For future readers.
I tested both variants in terms of runtime and this are the results:

My initial command:
real    0m2.728s
user    0m0.173s
sys     0m2.385s

using the suggested "read" command:
real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.069s